# Problem with event JS table to list and click on checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, list

I have the following code, in practice I have two problems, the first is that when I convert from table to list the events in jquery no longer work. the second problem is that I can't perform a .trigger ('click'); on a checkbox if I click on its relative there.

can you please help me?

HTML START WITH TABLE

```
....

<table id="table-files" class="uk-table uk-table-responsive uk-table-middle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="uk-table-shrink"><input name="checkbox-all-files" type="checkbox" class="uk-checkbox"></th>
            <th id="table-image" class="uk-table-shrink"></th>
            <th id="table-name" class="uk-table-expand">Name</th>
            <th id="table-file" class="uk-table-shrink">File</th>
            <th id="table-folder" class="uk-table-shrink">Folder</th>
            <th id="table-tools">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="check-files" data-user="2" data-file="10">
            <td><input name="checkbox-files" value="43" type="checkbox" class="uk-checkbox"></td>
            <td data-image="1"><img alt="User" src="/user/user_profile.jpg" width="60" height="60"></td>
            <td class="uk-text-nowrap">Mark Zu</td>
            <td class="uk-text-nowrap" name="tools-table"><a href="/files/Test.jpg">Test.jpg</a></td>
            <td class="uk-text-nowrap">Main</td>
            <td name="tools-table"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

....

<script src="/functions/table-to-ul.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/functions/files.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/functions/filesList.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

THE FUNCTION CONVERSION IS ON FILE TABLE-TO-UL.JS

```
function convert_table_to_list_files(table_id) {
    var list_id = table_id.replace("table-", "ul-");
    var ul = $("<ul id='"+list_id+"' class='uk-grid uk-grid-medium uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-3@l uk-child-width-1-4@xl' uk-grid uk-height-match='target: > div > .uk-card'>");
    $("#"+table_id+" tbody tr").each(function(){
        var classTR = this.className;
        var userTR = this.attributes["data-user"].value;
        var fileTR = this.attributes["data-file"].value;

        var li = $("<li class='"+classTR+"' data-user='"+userTR+"' data-file='"+fileTR+"'>");

        var checkboxCell = this.children[0].innerHTML;
        var ImgCell = this.children[1].attributes["data-image"].value;
        var userCell = this.children[2].innerHTML;
        var fileCell = this.children[3].innerHTML;
        var fileHrefCell = this.children[3].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.href;

        var resultOutput = `<div class="uk-card uk-card-box">
            <div class="uk-card-teaser uk-position-relative">
                <div class="uk-background-cover" style="background-image: url('`+fileHrefCell+`');">
                </div> 
            <canvas width="1200" height="800"></canvas> 
            </div>
            <div class="uk-text-truncate"><div class="uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle">`+
                checkboxCell+`<span>`+fileCell+`</span>`+
                `</div><hr>`+
                `<div data-image="`+ImgCell+`">`+userCell+`</div>`
            +`</div>
        </div>`;

        li.append(output);
        ul.append(li);
    })
    $("table#"+table_id).replaceWith(ul);
}
```

THE FUNCTION START WHEN CLICK ON BUTTON IN FILES.JS THERE ARE THE EVENT CLICK:

```
 $(function() {

    $('a[id=system-change-table]').click(function(){
        convert_table_to_list_files("table-files");
    });

});
```

IN FILE FILESLIST.JS THERE ARE SOME FUNCTION EVENT:

```
$(function() {
    $('#table-files tbody').on("click", "tr", function(event) {
        var td_id = $(event.target).closest('td').attr('name');
        if((event.target.type == 'checkbox') || (td_id == 'tools-table')){
        }else{
            var checkbox = $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
            if($(checkbox).is(":checked")){
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass("uk-active");
            }else{
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("uk-active");
            } 
        }
    });

    $('#ul-files').on("click", "li", function(event) {
        var checkbox_type = $(event.target).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr('name');
        if(checkbox_type){
            var checkbox = $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
            if($(checkbox).is(":checked")){
                $(this).closest('li').addClass("uk-active");
            }else{
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass("uk-active");
            }
        }
    });

  ....
});
```

Now as I said if I do not start the conversion, the click function on the table tr works, while the click function does not.
If I start the conversion the function stops working. Also in the conversion if I have the checkbox clicked it does not convert it to the checked one even if in the attribute it shows it to me with true.
Thank you all

First problem resolve when i change this

$('#table-files tbody').on("click", "tr", function(event) {

to

$(document.body).on('click', '#table-files tbody tr' ,function(){

work.

Now the problem is status checked not copy in html and not checked input checkbox in list

Comment: Try `$('#table-files tbody').on("click", "tr", function(event) {` to `$(document.body).on('click', '#table-files tbody tr' ,function(){`

Comment: @itzMEonTV thanks so it works, but I still have problems on two things:
1) if I click on <li> it should check the chebox that contains, but it doesn't work.
2) if I change from table to list and I have a clicked checkbox it does not put it checked on the list